# How to resolve broken packages after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, upgrade

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu Server 14.04 to 16.04, the upgrade process was interrupted in the last step, after that I cannot use `apt` to install any software because of broken packages also the kernel was not upgraded.

`apt-get upgrade` gives me these errors

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cron
 initscripts
 procps
 udev
 plymouth
 mountall
 dbus
 accountsservice
 language-selector-common
 uuid-runtime
 apache2
 grub-common
 grub2-common
 grub-pc-bin
 grub-pc
 mysql-server-5.7
 ntp
 keyboard-configuration
 console-setup
 kbd
 console-setup-linux
 anacron
 logrotate
 resolvconf
 rsyslog
 irqbalance
 cgroup-lite
 cgmanager
 systemd-shim
 libpam-systemd:amd64
 plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text
 rsync
 ubuntu-standard
 acct
 at
 biosdevname
 screen
 policykit-1
 colord
 ipmitool
 netfilter-persistent
 iptables-persistent
 postfix
 iwatch
 logwatch
 lvm2
 mailutils
 mysql-server
 rpcbind
 nfs-common
 nfs-kernel-server
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I resolve them please?

Comment: Did you tried `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: @N0rbert Yes I tried and got the same output

Answer (score 2):

I had another error which I did not post here and it appeared to be the one causing all these issues.

`insserv: There is a loop between service monit and sshd-monit if stopped`

I deleted `/etc/init.d/sshd-monit` and the problem was solved.

Comment: In another server I had also to delete `/etc/init.d/hst` too

Comment: On another server I had this issue `insserv: Service mountdevsubfs has to be enabled to start service hwclock` and it was resolved using `rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/util-linux.postinst && apt-get dist-upgrade -f`